# Bash operator translation to fish

Tags: bash, io-redirection, fish

I've been trying to learn to use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and for bash it uses the `<<<` operator which I cannot understand after reading the [bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.pdf), what is this operator for?

Besides that, I use the fish shell instead. How can I translate `jq . <<< '{"some": "xyz"}'` (works in bash) to the fish shell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<<<` operator is a here-string

[3.6.7 Here Strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings)

Given:

```
[n]<<< word
```

> The word undergoes brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal. Pathname expansion and word splitting are not performed. The result is supplied as a single string, with a newline appended, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor n if n is specified).

To translate this to fish shell you could likely do:

```
echo '{"some": "xyz"}' | jq
```

(which would work in `bash` as well)